# Исключение при задании ToolStripStatusLabel свойства Visible true

Tags: c#

При задании свойства `Visible` в true у `ToolStripStatusLabel` вылетает исключение

**ArgumentOutOfRangeException**

> Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным
>   числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции. Имя
>   параметра: index

Что за индекс и какое отношение имеет к свойству `Visible` ?

```
void address_OnResultReadRegU(ModBus2.RegU sender, ModBus2.ModBusCommon.Error result, ushort data)
{
    if (data == 0)
    {
        Status.SetImage = StatusLabel.State.GRAY;
        Status.Visible = false;
    }
    else
        Status.Visible = true;
}

public class StatusLabel : ToolStripStatusLabel
{
    public enum State
    {
        GRAY,
        GREEN,
        RED
    }

    public StatusLabel()
    {
        this.Image = Properties.Resources.gray_state;
        this.Text = "Модуль";
        this.Visible = false;
    }

    public State SetImage
    {
        set
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                case State.GRAY:
                    this.Image = Properties.Resources.gray_state;
                    break;

                case State.GREEN:
                    this.Image = Properties.Resources.green_state;
                    break;

                case State.RED:
                    this.Image = Properties.Resources.red_state;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Более полное сообщение о исключении

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException не обработано пользовательским
>   кодом
>   HResult=-2146233086
>   Message=Индекс за пределами диапазона.
>   Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен
>   превышать размер коллекции. Имя параметра: index   Source=mscorlib
>   ParamName=index   StackTrace:
>          в System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutStyleCollection.System.Collections.IList.get_Item(Int32
>   index)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Layout.TableLayout.IsAbsolutelySized(Int32 index,
>   IList styles)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Layout.TableLayout.InflateRows(ContainerInfo
>   containerInfo, Size proposedConstraints, Int32 expandLastElementWidth,
>   Boolean measureOnly)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Layout.TableLayout.ApplyStyles(ContainerInfo
>   containerInfo, Size proposedConstraints, Boolean measureOnly)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Layout.TableLayout.LayoutCore(IArrangedElement
>   container, LayoutEventArgs args)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Layout.LayoutEngine.Layout(Object container, LayoutEventArgs layoutEventArgs)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs
>   levent)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.StatusStrip.OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs levent)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Control.PerformLayout(LayoutEventArgs args)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Control.System.Windows.Forms.Layout.IArrangedElement.PerformLayout(IArrangedElement
>   affectedElement, String affectedProperty)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.DoLayoutIfHandleCreated(ToolStripItemEventArgs
>   e)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnItemVisibleChanged(ToolStripItemEventArgs
>   e, Boolean performLayout)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.OnVisibleChanged(EventArgs e)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.SetVisibleCore(Boolean visible)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.set_Visible(Boolean value)
>          в RATMM.Modules.GuiModuleDIN4.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Object
>   , EventArgs ) в
>   D:\doc\C#\R-AT-MM-Link_v2\R-AT-MM-Link_v2\Modules\GuiModuleDIN4.cs:строка
>   48   InnerException:

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос.

Comment: И полную информацию по исключению (вызовите у исключения `ToString()`).

Answer (score 1):

У вас `TableLayoutPanel` неправильно настроена (не хватает строк).

Связь с `Visible` - простая. Когда меняется видимость или количество дочерних элементов, `TableLayoutPanel` начинает перестраивать макет. Вот во время это перестройки ошибка и возникает.

Comment: Ок, ToolStripStatusLabel расположен в StatusStrip. Где можно настроить количество строк?